# URI Regex: Replace http://, https://, ftp:// with empty string if URL valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, uri, validation

I have a simple URL validator. The url validator works as probably every other validator.

Now I want, if the URL passed, take the https://, http:// and remove it for `var b`.

So what I've done is I made a another Regex which captures https://, http://, ftp:// etc and say if the url passed the long test, get the second test and replace it with empty string.

Here is what I came up with:

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
   var url = $('#in').val();

   var match = /^([a-z][a-z0-9\*\-\.]*):\/\/(?:(?:(?:[\w\.\-\+!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+:)*(?:[\w\.\-\+%!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+@)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+|(?:\[(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:)*(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4})\]))(?::[0-9]+)?(?:[\/|\?](?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&@!$'~*,;\/\(\)\[\]\-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?$/;
   var protomatch = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(.*)/;


   if (match.test(url)) { // IF VALID
      console.log(url + ' is valid');

      // if valid replace http, https, ftp etc with empty
      var b = url.replace(protomatch.test(url), '');
      console.log(b)

   } else { // IF INVALID
      console.log('not valid')
   }

});
```

Why this doesn't work?

Comment: because protomatch.test(url) returns true or false, not a string

Comment: The regex you're using there is well beyond the bounds of sanity. You must break it up, otherwise it is an unmanageable, unintelligible, unmaintainable heap of characters and in this state it won't do you any good. Try a staged approach: Stage one: Basic structural test, catching those basic structures into groups. Stage 2: More basic tests on the groups to determine their contents: Stage 3: Individual validity tests and value extraction from those. Yes, it is a little more code, but it won't make your head hurt and it will have less bugs.

Comment: @tomalak I choosed it from here: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex. Im struggling to create my own entire Regex and I find this to fit my needs

Comment: @jQuerybeast Well, if you can't understand it, you should not use it. And frankly, this one is not okay (I'm good with regex, I can tell).

Comment: So you went to that website, and didn't pick the one that passed _all_ of the tests?!

Comment: It was pretty much doing everything I wanted. I switched it to this: https://gist.github.com/729294

Comment: @alnitak I picked the one that its suitable for me. The guy who did the tests, he choosed what he wants. I choosed what I want. Its a no-brainer isnt it? He doesn't want Ip's, I do. He wants chinese, I dont.

Comment: the "winning" regexp does support IPs, so long as they're not from unexpected ranges (e.g. RFC 1918, multicast, etc).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`protomatch.test()` returns a boolean, not a string.

I think you just want:

```
var protomatch = /^(https?|ftp):\/\//; // NB: not '.*'
...
var b = url.replace(protomatch, '');
```

FWIW, your `match` regexp is completely impenetrable, and almost certainly wrong.  It probably doesn't permit internationalised domains, but it's so hard to read that I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Great. I should test protomotach.test() on console. Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

```
var b = url.substr(url.indexOf('://')+3);
```

Comment: this will remove _any_ URL scheme identifier, not just `https`, `http` and `ftp`.

Comment: what happens if the url itself not contains http or https at some cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more generic approach, like Yuri's, but which will work for more cases:

```
var b = url.replace(/^.*:\/\//i, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an empty protocol, like: //example.com, so relying on '://' may not cover all cases.